# Is the pointer passed to placement new a non-UB pointer to its object representation?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
struct foo {
   int a;
   int b;
};

std::array<char, sizeof(foo)> buffer;
foo a {1, 2};
foo* b {new (buffer.data()) foo};
std::memcpy(buffer.data(), &a, sizeof(foo));
a == *b; // the important part
```

I know that the placement new leaves the values of `b`'s fields indeterminate, but does the subsequent memcpy, through the pointer to the buffer passed to `new`, then turn `b` into a copy of `a`? Or is there UB, since I'm not `memcpy`-ing through the pointer returned by `new`?

cppreference ended being a bit too obtuse for me, in this case, to figure out if this is defined or not.

Edit: assume `buffer` is properly aligned to make the placement new make sense

Comment: `new (buffer.data()) foo` is most probably UB, because `buffer.data()` is most probably not aligned to `alignof(foo)`. Use `std::aligned_storage`..

Comment: `std::memcpy(buffer.data(), &a, sizeof(foo));` is UB for 2 reasons: `buffer.data()` points to objects outside their lifetime, so `memcpy` will access objects outside lifetime. And since it is already UB, I don't need to write about the 2nd reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Placement new
>
> If placement_params are provided, they are passed to the allocation
>   function as additional arguments. Such allocation functions are known
>   as "placement new", after the standard allocation function void*
>   operator new(std::size_t, void*), which simply returns its second
>   argument unchanged. This is used to construct objects in allocated
>   storage:

The above is from cppreference, so you are correct after memcpy the memory contents of 'b' is the same as 'a'

Source : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: So based on type aliasing rules,`buffer.data()` is an allowed alias for `b` (since it's `char*`). Is placement `new` guaranteed to produce a pointer with the same "address" as the passed one (i.e., they are actually aliases of each other)?

Comment: From the language it seems to me the second is always guaranteed. Although, derefrencing buffer.data() won't yield a type of foo. The original comments on the question pose a valid problem, you will have to ensue the the lifetime of the buffer.data() matches with your expectation.